# styling wordpress posts on homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Ok I'm a newbie to wordpress design and I find the wordpress codex too advanced for beginners like me.

Well my blog home page displays `15 posts` and I've successfully implemented a featured slider which displays the newest 5 post. Now, I want display the `previous (5) post` in a jquery carousel but I don't even know how to go about this. Any help about how to go about this guys?  I posted this problem in the wordpress.stackoverflow area but no reply. It's taken me forever to implement this :(

Comment: Are the previous posts going to be on the front page, above (below) the current featured slider? Have you checked for Plug-ins?

Comment: it's going to be below the featured slider. And there's know plugins for the carousel. How do I tell wordpress to display the 5 old post in the jquery carousel? :(

I mean like this:-
5 latest post -> slider
5 old post -> in the carousel

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin is using WP functions, you could just try changing the "offset" parameter. Notice the offset parameter which you can adjust according to your need.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 5, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```